# I can't get two jQuery slides to work simultaneously

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get two jQuery slides to work in a HTML page. 
I can't seem to get both of the slides to work simultaneously, however I can make one work at a time. Individually both slides work well, it's only when I include them on one HTML page when I get an issue.

Please help me understand why the two jQuery slides cant work simultaneously on one page.

**Find the source code for the HTML page below:**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Testing two Sliders</title>
</head>

<body>

 <!-- ##### First Slide #### --> 
 <?php include("homeSliderOrg.html");?>

<br> <br>

 <!-- ##### Second Slide #### -->  
 <?php include("easyAccordian.html");?> 

</body>
</html>
```

**Find below the Source Code to the first slide**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Lof JSliderNews 1.0 - Jquery 1.3</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/layout.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style0.css" />
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $( function(){ 
        $('#lofslidecontent45').lofJSidernews( { interval:4000,
                                                easing:'easeOutBounce',
                                                duration:1200,
                                                auto:true } );                      
    });

</script>
<style>
    .lof-snleft  .lof-main-outer{
        float:right;
    }
    /* move the main wapper to the right side */
    .lof-snleft .lof-main-wapper{
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:inherit;
        clear:both;
        height:300px;
    }
    /* move the navigator to the left  side */
    .lof-snleft .lof-navigator-outer{
        left:0;
        top:0;
        right:inherit;

    }

    ul.lof-main-wapper li {
        position:relative;  
    }
    .lof-snleft .lof-navigator .active{
        background:url(images/arrow-bg2.gif) center right no-repeat;
    }
    .lof-snleft .lof-navigator li div{
        margin-left:inherit;
        margin-right:18px;
    }

    .lof-snleft .lof-navigator li.active div{
        margin-left:inherit;
        margin-right:18px;
        background:url(images/grad-bg2.gif)

    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <!--    <h1><strong>Lof JSliderNews 1.0</strong> -  Jquery 1.3 & Easing plugin</h1> -->

<!------------------------------------- THE CONTENT ------------------------------------------------->
<div id="lofslidecontent45" class="lof-slidecontent  lof-snleft">
<div class="preload"><div></div></div>
 <!-- MAIN CONTENT --> 
  <div class="lof-main-outer">
    <ul class="lof-main-wapper">
        <li>
                <img src="images/791902news3.jpg" title="Newsflash 2" height="300" width="900">           
                 <div class="lof-main-item-desc">
                <h3><a target="_parent" title="Newsflash 2" href="#">Newsflash 2</a></h3>

                <p>The one thing about a Web site, it always changes! Joomla! makes it easy to add Articles, content,...</p>
             </div>
        </li> 
       <li>
            <img src="images/435576news10.jpg" title="Newsflash 1" height="300" width="900">            <div class="lof-main-item-desc">
                <h3><a target="_parent" title="Newsflash 1" href="#">Newsflash 1</a></h3>
                <p>Joomla! makes it easy to launch a Web site of any kind. Whether you want a brochure site or you are...</p>

             </div>
        </li> 
       <li>
            <img src="images/641906img1.jpg" title="Newsflash 3" height="300" width="900">            <div class="lof-main-item-desc">
                <h3><a target="_parent" title="Newsflash 3" href="#">Newsflash 3</a></h3>
                <p>With a library of thousands of free Extensions, you can add what you need as your site grows. Don't...</p>
             </div>
        </li> 
        <li>

            <img src="images/416719news7.jpg" title="Newsflash 5" height="300" width="900">            <div class="lof-main-item-desc">
                <h3><a target="_parent" title="Newsflash 5" href="#">Newsflash 5</a></h3>
                <p>Joomla! 1.5 - 'Experience the Freedom'!. It has never been easier to create your own dynamic Web...</p>
             </div>
        </li> 

        <li>

            <img src="images/416719news7.jpg" title="Newsflash 5" height="300" width="900">            <div class="lof-main-item-desc">
                <h3><a target="_parent" title="Newsflash 5" href="#">Newsflash 5</a></h3>
                <p>Joomla! 1.5 - 'Experience the Freedom'!. It has never been easier to create your own dynamic Web...</p>
             </div>
        </li> 
        <li>

            <img src="images/416719news7.jpg" title="Newsflash 5" height="300" width="900">            <div class="lof-main-item-desc">
                <h3><a target="_parent" title="Newsflash 5" href="#">Newsflash 5</a></h3>
                <p>Joomla! 1.5 - 'Experience the Freedom'!. It has never been easier to create your own dynamic Web...</p>
             </div>
        </li> 
      </ul>     
  </div>
  <!-- END MAIN CONTENT --> 
    <!-- NAVIGATOR -->

  <div class="lof-navigator-outer">
        <ul class="lof-navigator">
            <li>
                <div>
                    <img src="images/lofthumbs/791902news3.jpg" />
                    <h3> NewsFlash 1 </h3>
                    <span>20.01.2010</span> - In id, mauris viverra asperiores, bibendum in id. Eu molestie. Ac sit eu...
                </div>    
            </li>
             <li>
                <div>
                    <img src="images/lofthumbs/435576news10.jpg" />
                    <h3> NewsFlash 2 </h3>
                    <span>20.01.2010</span> -In id, mauris viverra asperiores, bibendum in id. Eu molestie. Ac sit eu. ..
                </div>    
            </li>

            <li>
                <div>
                    <img src="images/lofthumbs/641906img1.jpg" />
                    <h3> NewsFlash 3 </h3>
                    <span>20.01.2010</span> - In id, mauris viverra asperiores, bibendum in id. Eu molestie. Ac sit eu. ..
                </div>     
            </li>

           <li>
                <div>
                    <img src="images/lofthumbs/416719news7.jpg" />
                    <h3> NewsFlash 4</h3>
                    <span>20.01.2010</span> - In id, mauris viverra asperiores, bibendum in id. Eu molestie. Ac sit eu. ..
                </div>
            </li>    
            <li>
                 <div>
                    <img src="images/lofthumbs/641906img1.jpg" />
                    <h3> NewsFlash 5</h3>
                    <span>20.01.2010</span> -In id, mauris viverra asperiores, bibendum in id. Eu molestie. Ac sit eu. ..
                 </div>   
            </li>
           <li>
                <div>
                    <img src="images/lofthumbs/416719news7.jpg" />
                    <h3> NewsFlash 6</h3>
                    <span>20.01.2010</span> - In id, mauris viverra asperiores, bibendum in id. Eu molestie. Ac sit eu. ..
                </div>
            </li>           
        </ul>
  </div>
 </div> 
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>

<!------------------------------------- END OF THE CONTENT ------------------------------------------------->
<!-- <p> 
<a href="index.html">Demo 1</a>  | <a href="index2.html">Demo 2</a>  |  <a href="index3.html">Demo 3</a> | <a href="index4.html">Demo 4</a> | <a href="index5.html">Demo 5</a> | <a href="index6.html">Demo 6</a> </p>
-->

<!--
<div id="footer">
  <a href="http://landofcoder.com">LandOfCoder.Com</a>

</div>
-->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Find below the Source Code to the second slide**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
      <title>jQuery Easy Accordion Plugin</title>

      <!-- Meta -->
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
      <meta name="author" content="Andrea Cima Serniotti - Madeincima.eu" />
      <meta name="description" content="jQuery Easy Accordion Plugin - A highly flexible timed horizontal slider able to show any kind of content" />
      <meta name="keywords" content="jQuery, plugin, accordion, slider, slideshow, horizontal, timed, interval" />    

      <!-- Scripts -->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easyAccordion.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/utility.js"></script>

      <style type="text/css">
          html{font-size:62.5%}
          body{font-size:1.2em;color:#294f88}
          .sample{margin:0px;border:1px solid #92cdec;background:#white;padding:0px}
          h1{margin:0 0 20px 0;padding:0;font-size:2em;}
          h2{margin:40px 0 20px 0;padding:0;font-size:1.6em;}
          .easy-accordion h2{margin:0px 0 20px 0;padding:0;font-size:1.6em;}
          p{font-size:1.2em;line-height:170%;margin-bottom:20px}


        /* UNLESS YOU KNOW WHAT YOU'RE DOING, DO NOT CHANGE THE FOLLOWING RULES */

        .easy-accordion{display:block;position:relative;overflow:hidden;padding:0;margin:0}
        .easy-accordion dt,.easy-accordion dd{margin:0;padding:0}
        .easy-accordion dt,.easy-accordion dd{position:absolute}
        .easy-accordion dt{margin-bottom:0;margin-left:0;z-index:5;/* Safari */ -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Firefox */ -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);-moz-transform-origin: 20px 0px;  /* Internet Explorer */ filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);cursor:pointer;}
        .easy-accordion dd{z-index:1;opacity:0;overflow:hidden}
        .easy-accordion dd.active{opacity:1;}
        .easy-accordion dd.no-more-active{z-index:2;opacity:1}
        .easy-accordion dd.active{z-index:3}
        .easy-accordion dd.plus{z-index:4}
        .easy-accordion .slide-number{position:absolute;bottom:0;left:10px;font-weight:normal;font-size:1.1em;/* Safari */ -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Firefox */ -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);  /* Internet Explorer */ filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1);}


        /* FEEL FREE TO CUSTOMIZE THE FOLLOWING RULES */

        dd p{line-height:120%}

        #accordion-1{width:800px;height:245px;padding:30px;background:#fff;border:1px solid #b5c9e8}
        #accordion-1 dl{width:800px;height:245px}   
        #accordion-1 dt{height:46px;line-height:44px;text-align:right;padding:0 15px 0 0;font-size:1.1em;font-weight:bold;font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;text-transform:uppercase;letter-spacing:1px;background:#fff url(images/slide-title-inactive-1.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;color:#26526c}
        #accordion-1 dt.active{cursor:pointer;color:#fff;background:#fff url(images/slide-title-active-1.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat}
        #accordion-1 dt.hover{color:#68889b;}
        #accordion-1 dt.active.hover{color:#fff}
        #accordion-1 dd{padding:25px;background:url(images/slide.jpg) bottom left repeat-x;border:1px solid #dbe9ea;border-left:0;margin-right:3px}
        #accordion-1 .slide-number{color:#68889b;left:10px;font-weight:bold}
        #accordion-1 .active .slide-number{color:#fff;}
        #accordion-1 a{color:#68889b}
        #accordion-1 dd img{float:right;margin:0 0 0 30px;}
        #accordion-1 h2{font-size:2.5em;margin-top:10px}
        #accordion-1 .more{padding-top:10px;display:block}

        #accordion-2{width:700px;height:195px;padding:30px;background:#fff;border:1px solid #b5c9e8}
        #accordion-2 h2{font-size:2.5em;margin-top:10px}
        #accordion-2 dl{width:700px;height:195px}   
        #accordion-2 dt{height:56px;line-height:44px;text-align:right;padding:10px 15px 0 0;font-size:1.1em;font-weight:bold;font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;text-transform:uppercase;letter-spacing:1px;background:#fff url(images/slide-title-inactive-2.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;color:#26526c}
        #accordion-2 dt.active{cursor:pointer;color:#fff;background:#fff url(images/slide-title-active-2.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat}
        #accordion-2 dt.hover{color:#68889b;}
        #accordion-2 dt.active.hover{color:#fff}
        #accordion-2 dd{padding:25px;background:url(images/slide.jpg) bottom left repeat-x;border:1px solid #dbe9ea;border-left:0;margin-right:3px}
        #accordion-2 .slide-number{color:#68889b;left:10px;font-weight:bold}
        #accordion-2 .active .slide-number{color:#fff}
        #accordion-2 a{color:#68889b}
        #accordion-2 dd img{float:right;margin:0 0 0 30px;position:relative;top:-20px}

        #accordion-3{width:700px;height:195px;padding:30px;background:#fff;border:1px solid #b5c9e8}
        #accordion-3 h2{font-size:2.5em;margin-top:10px}
        #accordion-3 dl{width:700px;height:195px}   
        #accordion-3 dt{height:56px;line-height:44px;text-align:right;padding:10px 15px 0 0;font-size:1.1em;font-weight:bold;font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;text-transform:uppercase;letter-spacing:1px;background:#fff url(images/slide-title-inactive-2.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;color:#26526c}
        #accordion-3 dt.active{cursor:pointer;color:#fff;background:#fff url(images/slide-title-active-2.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat}
        #accordion-3 dt.hover{color:#68889b;}
        #accordion-3 dt.active.hover{color:#fff}
        #accordion-3 dd{padding:25px;background:url(images/slide.jpg) bottom left repeat-x;border:1px solid #dbe9ea;border-left:0;margin-right:3px}
        #accordion-3 .slide-number{color:#68889b;left:13px;font-weight:bold}
        #accordion-3 .active .slide-number{color:#fff}
        #accordion-3 a{color:#68889b}
        #accordion-3 dd img{float:right;margin:0 0 0 30px;position:relative;top:-20px}

      </style>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="sample">
<!--        <h1>Career Guidance Pro</h1>

        <h2>Welcomes you</h2>
-->
        <div id="accordion-1">
            <dl>
                <dt>First slide</dt> 
                <dd><h2>Your journey to success starts here!</h2><p><img src="images/monsters/img1.png" alt="Alt text to go here" />Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, enim.<br /><a href="#" class="more">Read more</a></p></dd>
                <dt>Second slide</dt>
                <dd><h2>Our success rate is based on:</h2><p><img src="images/monsters/img2.png" alt="Alt text to go here" />Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, enim.<br /><a href="#" class="more">Read more</a></p></dd>
                <dt>One more slide</dt>
                <dd><h2>Scientifically validated career guidance tools</h2><p><img src="images/monsters/img3.png" alt="Alt text to go here" />Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, enim.<br /><a href="#" class="more">Read more</a></p></dd>
                <dt>Another slide</dt>
                <dd><h2>Another slide to go here</h2><p><img src="images/monsters/img4.png" alt="Alt text to go here" />Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, enim.<br /><a href="#" class="more">Read more</a></p></dd>
                <dt>Wow one more</dt>
                <dd><h2>Unbilievable one more slide here</h2><p><img src="images/monsters/img5.png" alt="Alt text to go here" />Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, enim.<br /><a href="#" class="more">Read more</a></p></dd>
                <dt>Last one</dt>
                <dd><h2>This is definitely the last one</h2><p><img src="images/monsters/img6.png" alt="Alt text to go here" />Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, enim.<br /><a href="#" class="more">Read more</a></p></dd>
            </dl>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: too much code, you can't read it properly, could you make a jsfiddle for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to start by looking at both your included html files.
Including two different jquery instances will cause trouble right off the bat.

First slide:

```
script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"
```

Second slide:

```
script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js
```

Instead do a single jquery script on the page referencing your slides included in the main page `<head>` tag.

If after doing this one still does not work, check for duplicate id's in all of your elements between both .html files.

Comment: Thank you so much. I followed your advice and it now WORKS! I wasted alot of hours trying to figure out what the problem was. Your advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi Datafreak, I just realized that it only works on my local server but when I upload it to my webhost I cant get it to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To start, if you include both those pages as you are above then you'll end up with a page with 3 sets of `<html>` tags and 3 `<head>` sections, 3 `<body>`'s etc.

You'll also end up including JQuery more than once, which can cause problems.

You'd be better creating one page (i.e. 1 set of `<html>`, `<head>`, and `<body>` tags), and just create new instances for each slideshow on that page.

Creating an instance on div with id="lofslidecontent45" :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $( function(){ 
        $('#lofslidecontent45').lofJSidernews( { 
           interval:4000,
           easing:'easeOutBounce',
           duration:1200,
           auto:true 
         } );                      
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Nick, do you think you could demonstrate how to create an instance of a slide?

Comment: Thats in your page code already, but I've edited my answer to include an example.

Comment: Oh thank you for making it very clear. Your answer is very much appreciated