# Why do all my JQuery sliders show locally but not on my Webhost?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a page with two JQuery sliders. 
Locally both jquery sliders work perfectly, however when I publish them on my web-host only one of them (the bottom one) works. I naturally want both of them to function properly.

Can anyone shine some light on this issue?

**Find below the source code to the page with the two sliders**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Testing two Sliders</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/layout.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style0.css" />
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easyAccordion.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/utility.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready ( function(){    
        $('#lofslidecontent45').lofJSidernews( { interval:4000,
        easing:'easeOutBounce',
        duration:1200,
        auto:true } );                      
    });

</script>

<style>
    .lof-snleft  .lof-main-outer{
        float:right;
    }
    /* move the main wapper to the right side */
    .lof-snleft .lof-main-wapper{
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:inherit;
        clear:both;
        height:300px;
    }
    /* move the navigator to the left  side */
    .lof-snleft .lof-navigator-outer{
        left:0;
        top:0;
        right:inherit;

    }

    ul.lof-main-wapper li {
        position:relative;  
    }
    .lof-snleft .lof-navigator .active{
        background:url(images/arrow-bg2.gif) center right no-repeat;
    }
    .lof-snleft .lof-navigator li div{
        margin-left:inherit;
        margin-right:18px;
    }

    .lof-snleft .lof-navigator li.active div{
        margin-left:inherit;
        margin-right:18px;
        background:url(images/grad-bg2.gif)

    }
</style>

      <style type="text/css">
          html{font-size:62.5%}
          body{font-size:1.2em;color:#294f88}
          .sample{margin:0px;border:1px solid #92cdec;background:#white;padding:0px}
          h1{margin:0 0 20px 0;padding:0;font-size:2em;}
          h2{margin:40px 0 20px 0;padding:0;font-size:1.6em;}
          .easy-accordion h2{margin:0px 0 20px 0;padding:0;font-size:1.6em;}
          p{font-size:1.2em;line-height:170%;margin-bottom:20px}


        /* UNLESS YOU KNOW WHAT YOU'RE DOING, DO NOT CHANGE THE FOLLOWING RULES */

        .easy-accordion{display:block;position:relative;overflow:hidden;padding:0;margin:0}
        .easy-accordion dt,.easy-accordion dd{margin:0;padding:0}
        .easy-accordion dt,.easy-accordion dd{position:absolute}
        .easy-accordion dt{margin-bottom:0;margin-left:0;z-index:5;/* Safari */ -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Firefox */ -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);-moz-transform-origin: 20px 0px;  /* Internet Explorer */ filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);cursor:pointer;}
        .easy-accordion dd{z-index:1;opacity:0;overflow:hidden}
        .easy-accordion dd.active{opacity:1;}
        .easy-accordion dd.no-more-active{z-index:2;opacity:1}
        .easy-accordion dd.active{z-index:3}
        .easy-accordion dd.plus{z-index:4}
        .easy-accordion .slide-number{position:absolute;bottom:0;left:10px;font-weight:normal;font-size:1.1em;/* Safari */ -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Firefox */ -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);  /* Internet Explorer */ filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1);}


        /* FEEL FREE TO CUSTOMIZE THE FOLLOWING RULES */

        dd p{line-height:120%}

        #accordion-1{width:800px;height:245px;padding:30px;background:#fff;border:1px solid #b5c9e8}
        #accordion-1 dl{width:800px;height:245px}   
        #accordion-1 dt{height:46px;line-height:44px;text-align:right;padding:0 15px 0 0;font-size:1.1em;font-weight:bold;font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;text-transform:uppercase;letter-spacing:1px;background:#fff url(images/slide-title-inactive-1.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;color:#26526c}
        #accordion-1 dt.active{cursor:pointer;color:#fff;background:#fff url(images/slide-title-active-1.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat}
        #accordion-1 dt.hover{color:#68889b;}
        #accordion-1 dt.active.hover{color:#fff}
        #accordion-1 dd{padding:25px;background:url(images/slide.jpg) bottom left repeat-x;border:1px solid #dbe9ea;border-left:0;margin-right:3px}
        #accordion-1 .slide-number{color:#68889b;left:10px;font-weight:bold}
        #accordion-1 .active .slide-number{color:#fff;}
        #accordion-1 a{color:#68889b}
        #accordion-1 dd img{float:right;margin:0 0 0 30px;}
        #accordion-1 h2{font-size:2.5em;margin-top:10px}
        #accordion-1 .more{padding-top:10px;display:block}

        #accordion-2{width:700px;height:195px;padding:30px;background:#fff;border:1px solid #b5c9e8}
        #accordion-2 h2{font-size:2.5em;margin-top:10px}
        #accordion-2 dl{width:700px;height:195px}   
        #accordion-2 dt{height:56px;line-height:44px;text-align:right;padding:10px 15px 0 0;font-size:1.1em;font-weight:bold;font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;text-transform:uppercase;letter-spacing:1px;background:#fff url(images/slide-title-inactive-2.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;color:#26526c}
        #accordion-2 dt.active{cursor:pointer;color:#fff;background:#fff url(images/slide-title-active-2.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat}
        #accordion-2 dt.hover{color:#68889b;}
        #accordion-2 dt.active.hover{color:#fff}
        #accordion-2 dd{padding:25px;background:url(images/slide.jpg) bottom left repeat-x;border:1px solid #dbe9ea;border-left:0;margin-right:3px}
        #accordion-2 .slide-number{color:#68889b;left:10px;font-weight:bold}
        #accordion-2 .active .slide-number{color:#fff}
        #accordion-2 a{color:#68889b}
        #accordion-2 dd img{float:right;margin:0 0 0 30px;position:relative;top:-20px}

        #accordion-3{width:700px;height:195px;padding:30px;background:#fff;border:1px solid #b5c9e8}
        #accordion-3 h2{font-size:2.5em;margin-top:10px}
        #accordion-3 dl{width:700px;height:195px}   
        #accordion-3 dt{height:56px;line-height:44px;text-align:right;padding:10px 15px 0 0;font-size:1.1em;font-weight:bold;font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;text-transform:uppercase;letter-spacing:1px;background:#fff url(images/slide-title-inactive-2.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;color:#26526c}
        #accordion-3 dt.active{cursor:pointer;color:#fff;background:#fff url(images/slide-title-active-2.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat}
        #accordion-3 dt.hover{color:#68889b;}
        #accordion-3 dt.active.hover{color:#fff}
        #accordion-3 dd{padding:25px;background:url(images/slide.jpg) bottom left repeat-x;border:1px solid #dbe9ea;border-left:0;margin-right:3px}
        #accordion-3 .slide-number{color:#68889b;left:13px;font-weight:bold}
        #accordion-3 .active .slide-number{color:#fff}
        #accordion-3 a{color:#68889b}
        #accordion-3 dd img{float:right;margin:0 0 0 30px;position:relative;top:-20px}

      </style>


</head>

<body>

 <!-- ##### First Slide #### --> 
     <div id="container">

<!------------------------------------- THE CONTENT ------------------------------------------------->
<div id="lofslidecontent45" class="lof-slidecontent  lof-snleft">
<div class="preload"><div></div></div>
 <!-- MAIN CONTENT --> 
  <div class="lof-main-outer">
    <ul class="lof-main-wapper">
        <li>
                <img src="images/791902news3.jpg" title="Newsflash 2" height="300" width="900">           
                 <div class="lof-main-item-desc">
                <h3><a target="_parent" title="Newsflash 2" href="#">Newsflash 2</a></h3>

                <p>The one thing about a Web site, it always changes! Joomla! makes it easy to add Articles, content,...</p>
             </div>
        </li> 
       <li>
            <img src="images/435576news10.jpg" title="Newsflash 1" height="300" width="900">            <div class="lof-main-item-desc">
                <h3><a target="_parent" title="Newsflash 1" href="#">Newsflash 1</a></h3>
                <p>Joomla! makes it easy to launch a Web site of any kind. Whether you want a brochure site or you are...</p>

             </div>
        </li> 
       <li>
            <img src="images/641906img1.jpg" title="Newsflash 3" height="300" width="900">            <div class="lof-main-item-desc">
                <h3><a target="_parent" title="Newsflash 3" href="#">Newsflash 3</a></h3>
                <p>With a library of thousands of free Extensions, you can add what you need as your site grows. Don't...</p>
             </div>
        </li> 
        <li>

            <img src="images/416719news7.jpg" title="Newsflash 5" height="300" width="900">            <div class="lof-main-item-desc">
                <h3><a target="_parent" title="Newsflash 5" href="#">Newsflash 5</a></h3>
                <p>Joomla! 1.5 - 'Experience the Freedom'!. It has never been easier to create your own dynamic Web...</p>
             </div>
        </li> 

        <li>

            <img src="images/416719news7.jpg" title="Newsflash 5" height="300" width="900">            <div class="lof-main-item-desc">
                <h3><a target="_parent" title="Newsflash 5" href="#">Newsflash 5</a></h3>
                <p>Joomla! 1.5 - 'Experience the Freedom'!. It has never been easier to create your own dynamic Web...</p>
             </div>
        </li> 
        <li>

            <img src="images/416719news7.jpg" title="Newsflash 5" height="300" width="900">            <div class="lof-main-item-desc">
                <h3><a target="_parent" title="Newsflash 5" href="#">Newsflash 5</a></h3>
                <p>Joomla! 1.5 - 'Experience the Freedom'!. It has never been easier to create your own dynamic Web...</p>
             </div>
        </li> 
      </ul>     
  </div>
  <!-- END MAIN CONTENT --> 
    <!-- NAVIGATOR -->

  <div class="lof-navigator-outer">
        <ul class="lof-navigator">
            <li>
                <div>
                    <img src="images/lofthumbs/791902news3.jpg" />
                    <h3> NewsFlash 1 </h3>
                    <span>20.01.2010</span> - In id, mauris viverra asperiores, bibendum in id. Eu molestie. Ac sit eu...
                </div>    
            </li>
             <li>
                <div>
                    <img src="images/lofthumbs/435576news10.jpg" />
                    <h3> NewsFlash 2 </h3>
                    <span>20.01.2010</span> -In id, mauris viverra asperiores, bibendum in id. Eu molestie. Ac sit eu. ..
                </div>    
            </li>

            <li>
                <div>
                    <img src="images/lofthumbs/641906img1.jpg" />
                    <h3> NewsFlash 3 </h3>
                    <span>20.01.2010</span> - In id, mauris viverra asperiores, bibendum in id. Eu molestie. Ac sit eu. ..
                </div>     
            </li>

           <li>
                <div>
                    <img src="images/lofthumbs/416719news7.jpg" />
                    <h3> NewsFlash 4</h3>
                    <span>20.01.2010</span> - In id, mauris viverra asperiores, bibendum in id. Eu molestie. Ac sit eu. ..
                </div>
            </li>    
            <li>
                 <div>
                    <img src="images/lofthumbs/641906img1.jpg" />
                    <h3> NewsFlash 5</h3>
                    <span>20.01.2010</span> -In id, mauris viverra asperiores, bibendum in id. Eu molestie. Ac sit eu. ..
                 </div>   
            </li>
           <li>
                <div>
                    <img src="images/lofthumbs/416719news7.jpg" />
                    <h3> NewsFlash 6</h3>
                    <span>20.01.2010</span> - In id, mauris viverra asperiores, bibendum in id. Eu molestie. Ac sit eu. ..
                </div>
            </li>           
        </ul>
  </div>
 </div> 

<br> <br>

 <!-- ##### Second Slide #### -->  

       <div id="accordion-1">
            <dl>
                <dt>First slide</dt> 
                <dd><h2>Your journey to success starts here!</h2><p><img src="images/monsters/img1.png" alt="Alt text to go here" />Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, enim.<br /><a href="#" class="more">Read more</a></p></dd>
                <dt>Second slide</dt>
                <dd><h2>Our success rate is based on:</h2><p><img src="images/monsters/img2.png" alt="Alt text to go here" />Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, enim.<br /><a href="#" class="more">Read more</a></p></dd>
                <dt>One more slide</dt>
                <dd><h2>Scientifically validated career guidance tools</h2><p><img src="images/monsters/img3.png" alt="Alt text to go here" />Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, enim.<br /><a href="#" class="more">Read more</a></p></dd>
                <dt>Another slide</dt>
                <dd><h2>Another slide to go here</h2><p><img src="images/monsters/img4.png" alt="Alt text to go here" />Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, enim.<br /><a href="#" class="more">Read more</a></p></dd>
                <dt>Wow one more</dt>
                <dd><h2>Unbilievable one more slide here</h2><p><img src="images/monsters/img5.png" alt="Alt text to go here" />Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, enim.<br /><a href="#" class="more">Read more</a></p></dd>
                <dt>Last one</dt>
                <dd><h2>This is definitely the last one</h2><p><img src="images/monsters/img6.png" alt="Alt text to go here" />Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, enim.<br /><a href="#" class="more">Read more</a></p></dd>
            </dl>
        </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880291/i-cant-get-two-jquery-slides-to-work-simultaneously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems confusion, and i see that you are using id in your jquery code for sliders, try replacing it with class, and add that class to the divs that enclose slider sections, like

```
$(document).ready ( function(){    
        $('.some_class').lofJSidernews( { interval:4000,
        easing:'easeOutBounce',
        duration:1200,
        auto:true } );                      
    });
//and use this "some_class" for your divs that contain slider elements
```

Hope it works for you

Comment: The id's are inside the main HTML code and not the the JQuery file. Nevertheless, I did try following your advice but i still cant seem to make it work. This is a Phenomenon as it works perfectly locally and not on the Webhost

Comment: I figured out what was causing the issue, using firebug, I found out that the reason the slide wasn't working remotely (on the webhost) was because I hadn't uploaded the required .js files. Thank you anyway.